TypeError: function takes 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
I am trying to interface multiple buttons with Esp8266 and display it on a 16x2 LCD. I am using micropython. Here is my code
import time
from machine import I2C, Pin, Timer
from i2c_lcd import I2cLcd

DEFAULT_I2C_ADDR = 0x27


class Button:
    def __init__(self, pin, callback):
        self.pin = Pin(pin, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
        self.callback = callback
        self.debounce_timer = Timer(-1)
        self.state = False

    def init(self):
        self.pin.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=self.interrupt_handler)
        print('Button initialized')

    def interrupt_handler(self):
        if not self.state:
            self.debounce_timer.init(period=50, mode=Timer.ONE_SHOT, callback=self.debounce_callback)       

    def debounce_callback(self):
        if not self.state and self.pin.value() == 0:
            self.callback()
        self.state = False


class Counter:
    def __init__(self, lcd):
        self.lcd = lcd
        self.count = 0

    def increment(self):
        print('Increament start')
        self.count += 1
        print('About to call update display')
        self.update_display()
        

    def decrement(self):
        self.count -= 1
        self.update_display()

    def update_display(self):
        print('Update display')
        self.lcd.move_to(11, 1)
        self.lcd.putstr("     ")
        self.lcd.move_to(11, 1)
        self.lcd.putstr(str(self.count))

i2c = I2C(scl=Pin(5), sda=Pin(4), freq=100000)
lcd = I2cLcd(i2c, DEFAULT_I2C_ADDR, 2, 16)

# Initialize counter
counter = Counter(lcd)

# Create a list of buttons
buttons = []


    
# Initialize buttons with their pins and callback functions (if any)
buttons.append(Button(13, counter.increment))  # Increment button
buttons.append(Button(14, counter.decrement))  # Decrement button


# Start all buttons
for button in buttons:
    button.init()
    
lcd.clear()
lcd.move_to(11, 0)
lcd.putstr("COUNT")

The code compiles fine buton as soon as I press an interrupt button, I get error
TypeError: function takes 1 positional arguments but 2 were given

I have been trying to debug for about an hour but not successful yet. I am not sure what is wrong.

You need to show us the full error message, including the line number.  Omitting that importing information makes it really hard to help you.

As per the micropython docs, interrupt handler expects Pin object. Here is my modified code which works fine.
import time
from machine import I2C, Pin, Timer
from i2c_lcd import I2cLcd

DEFAULT_I2C_ADDR = 0x27


class Button:
    def __init__(self, pin, callback):
        self.pin = Pin(pin, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
        self.callback = callback
        self.debounce_timer = Timer(-1)
        self.state = False

    def init(self):
        self.pin.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=self.interrupt_handler)

    def interrupt_handler(self, pin):
        if not self.state:
            self.debounce_timer.init(period=50, mode=Timer.ONE_SHOT, callback=self.debounce_callback)       

    def debounce_callback(self, pin):
        if not self.state and self.pin.value() == 0:            
            self.callback()
            self.state = False        


class Counter:
    def __init__(self, lcd):
        self.lcd = lcd
        self.count = 0

    def increment(self):
        print("Incrementing counter")
        self.count += 1
        self.update_display()
        

    def decrement(self):
        print("Decrementing counter")
        self.count -= 1
        self.update_display()

    def update_display(self):
        self.lcd.move_to(11, 1)
        self.lcd.putstr("     ")
        self.lcd.move_to(11, 1)
        self.lcd.putstr(str(self.count))

i2c = I2C(scl=Pin(5), sda=Pin(4), freq=100000)
lcd = I2cLcd(i2c, DEFAULT_I2C_ADDR, 2, 16)

# Initialize counter
counter = Counter(lcd)

# Create a list of buttons
buttons = []


    
# Initialize buttons with their pins and callback functions (if any)
buttons.append(Button(13, counter.increment))  # Increment button
#buttons.append(Button(14, counter.decrement))  # Decrement button


# Start all buttons
for button in buttons:
    button.init()
    
lcd.clear()
lcd.move_to(11, 0)
lcd.putstr("COUNT")

